# ASP.NET MVC Unobtrusive validation is not working on jquery tabs

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery-validate

I have a model with many fields. Thus I have used jQuery Tabs to render the fields on different tabs. When I hit the submit button, unobtrusive validation works only on the active tab. It doesn't work on other tabs. Thus it submits the form even thought there are errors on other tabs. However, server side validation works perfectly. Any idea to fix this problem on client side?

I have tried the following JS code.

```
var form = $(this);
$.validator.unobtrusive.parse(form);

if (form.valid()) 
{
    //submit to the server
}
```

I have found similar problem on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23998964/unobtrusive-validation-not-working-on-jquery-tabs-using-partial-view). But it doesn't help.

Comment: You need to change the validator [`ignore` option](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate#ignore). By default, it ignores `:hidden` form elements.

Comment: I tried ``form.validate({ ignore: "" });`` But it doesn't work.

Comment: that's because that isn't how you use jQuery Validate. You should have a look at the [docs](http://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation/) as it will probably be faster than trying to debug an issue using SO that is caused by not understanding the plugin. Check out [`setDefaults`](http://jqueryvalidation.org/jQuery.validator.setDefaults/)

Comment: This code works. ``var form = $(this); var validator = form.data('validator');validator.settings.ignore = "";`` Thanks Carrie